# What are these "property_" versions of published properties on my Polymer elements?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, polymer

When I inspect my polymer objects in Chrome Developer Tools, I find that for every published property, there's a version of the property that has a trailing underscore added. Both have the same values, but the original published property displays a value of `(...)` which must be clicked before I can see it.

E.g. if I publish a `height` property with a value of `23`, I'll see a `height: (...)` listing in Chrome Dev Tools and an additional `height_: 23` listing.

What purpose to these additional properties serve? Are there any issues with publishing properties that themselves have a trailing underscore, e.g. `height_`?

Comment: I found where it's created: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/instance/properties.js#L209 :)